# Blender 2.8 cycles on GPU compute just shows pink and purple noise?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

Any idea what's causing this? I'm set to render cycles with gpu compute. I have 2 geforce rtx 2080 ti's. All I'm getting is this pink and purple garbled mess..[image]

Comment: If you downloaded the file from the internet, chances are that the HDRi Background image wasn't included. You can also switch from Cycles to Eevee and see if stuff starts showing up. If that's the case you probably have a GPU/driver related problem.

Comment: looks like GPU driver related problem.

Answer (score -1):

Two things;

1: You used textures that you didn't pack into the file. That shade of magenta means the texture is missing. Find the textures and reload them.

2: You're going to need WAY more than 32 samples to get something usable. Start with 100, move up from there to get a more clear image.

Comment: You don't have to pack the textures into the file. This is only useful if you are going to transfer your work between computers. The textures - if there are any - just need to be at their specific locations.

Comment: Packed or not, blender doesn't have the data. Regardless of whether he wants to pack the textures in the future, he needs to find the textures and open them in the image texture node. I mentioned the packed file because I've only seen confusion like this when I file is moved to another system, and the user assumes the textures are packed in the file. Either way, the process is the same. Find them, load them.